# Is react-navigation ready for web development?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I am a user of `react-router` and discovered `react-navigation` while doing my first expo (SDK36) application.

I want to support web and native, after testing `react-navigation` demo, I wonder why there is a `web` compatibility if the example does not support the web.

Also, expo documentation [suggested](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/routing-and-navigation/) that we use the `react-router` library directly

#### Current Behavior

When I run on the `example` `expo start-web`,

I have compiling issue due to typescript:

```sh
 web  Failed to compile.
/home/dka/workspace/github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/example/App.tsx
SyntaxError: /home/dka/workspace/github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/example/App.tsx: Unexpected token (42:17)

  40 | import TabsInDrawer from './src/TabsInDrawer';
  41 | 
> 42 | const ExampleInfo: any = {
     |                  ^
  43 |   CustomTabUI: {
  44 |     description: 'Render additional views around a Tab navigator',
  45 |     name: 'Custom Tabs UI',
```

And the web showing:

[image]

#### Expected Behavior

I expect it to run on the web

#### How to reproduce

```
git clone git@github.com:react-navigation/react-navigation.git
cd react-navigation
git checkout v4.0.10
yarn bootstrap
cd example
npx expo start --web
```

#### Your Environment

```
| software         | version |
| ---------------- | ------- |
| react-navigation | v4.0.10 |
| react-native     | v0.59.8 | (through expo SDK33 used by the demo)
| node             | v13.5.0 |
| yarn             | v1.21.1 |
```

Is react-navigation ready for web development or should I got with react-router-dom for the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should use React Router for web.

Comment: 2 and a half years after this answer,  react-navigation is ready for web development with react-native-web!

Answer (score 0):

It claims to be working on web but the feature is ["experimental"](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html). There's no good community support for it and every other time reading through docs you'll find mentions that this or that feature doesn't work on the web. So I'd say it's not production ready for the web

edit: I am not using expo myself, but it looks like expo is using react-native-web rather than standard web, in which case you *should* be good to go